# Converting the drawn view into UIImage and add to UIImageView in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiview, uiimageview

I have app in which i am making sign with finger it works fine and it draws line but i want to save those lines drawn signature as image in ImageView to show screen but it is not showing i am using following code.

```
-(void)onSignButtonClick
{

    signatureView=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100,100,800,500)];

    signatureView.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];

    [self.view addSubview:signatureView];

    UIButton*OkButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [OkButton setFrame:CGRectMake(100,420,200,40)];
    [OkButton setTitle:@"OK" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [OkButton addTarget:self action:@selector(onOKButtonClick) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [signatureView addSubview:OkButton];

    drawScreen=[[MyLineDrawingView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,700,400)];
    [signatureView addSubview:drawScreen];
    [drawScreen release];
}


- (UIImage *)captureView {

    //hide controls if needed
        CGRect rect = [signatureView bounds];//use your signature view's Rect means Frame;
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        [self.view.layer renderInContext:context];   
        UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        return img;
}

-(void)onOKButtonClick{


    signatureView.hidden=YES;

    [self captureView];

      logoImageView.image=signatureImage;
}
```

Comment: [self captureView]; is return UIImage.. where you get that UIImage?

Comment: I got this code from site i think we need to get the return image can you please help me out in this

Comment: use logoImageView.image = [self captureView];

Comment: it is saving image but it is not saving the line which i am drawing in signatureView it is showing whole view

Comment: use : 

[self captureView];  signatureView.hidden=YES;

    logoImageView.image=signatureImage;

Comment: @JdeveloperIphone When you say `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()` it will give you entire context of current view. Instead you need to pass CGRect that needs to be captured `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size)`.

Comment: @Amar can you please edit in my code

Comment: @JdeveloperIphone dude check my new edit. I have edited it according to your question. the problem in your code is that you taking the image of self.view instead of self.signatureView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
-(void)onOKButtonClick {
    //first capture image from view
    CGRect rect = [signatureView bounds];   //use your signature view's Rect means Frame;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [signatureView.layer renderInContext:context];   //this line is also important for you
    UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    //take some part of image (crop image)
    UIImage *imgFinal = [self cropImage:img rect:CGRectMake(100,100,300,300)];
    logoImageView.image = imgFinal;

    signatureView.hidden=YES;
}

-(UIImage *)cropImage:(UIImage *)image rect:(CGRect)cropRect {
   CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([image CGImage], cropRect);
   UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef]; 
   CGImageRelease(imageRef);
   return img;
}
```

**problem occurs because your captureView method returns UIImage in definition but you cannot store it in method calling....**

Comment: this is working fine but it is possible that i may capture only the view mean if view is 500*500 but signature is done on 300*300 then it should only caputre 300*300 and then save it as image

Comment: or may i make the size of the image view smaller so that it fits in that beacuaue it is like a signaute and will be placed on document

Comment: see my edited answer for your problem solution....

Comment: i want that if my image should of same size as the size of logoImageView as per your code image is cutting

Comment: set **logoImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;** this property....

Comment: your problem is solved using this?

Answer (score 0):

replace your

```
logoImageView.image=signatureImage;
```

with

```
logoImageView.image = [self captureView];
```

**EDIT**

then replace

```
[self.view.layer renderInContext:context];
```

in your **captureView** method with this:

```
[self.signatureView.layer renderInContext:context];
```

Comment: i have done like this but it saves the main View not the signatureView   in which i am adding drawing as given in code

Comment: Check my new Edit please

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your method captureView. This works for me

```
**UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(tempV.frame.size);
 [[tempV layer] renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
 UIImage *screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
 UIGraphicsEndImageContext();**
```

and also chnage your function like this

```
-(void)onOKButtonClick{
signatureView.hidden=YEs;

    logoImageView.image=[self captureView];

}
```